# Why does my website has no "install app" option on chrome Android even after linking a web manifest, registering a service worker and hosting on https

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I'm learning how to create PWAs.
I hosted an example page on webhost000 with a webmanifest file and service worker.
The website passed the Chrome Lighthouse test and there are no errors in the console.
However, there are is an "Add to homescreen" Option instead of the "Install App" option which PWAs typically have.
Browser - Chrome Android
Here is the [link](https://projectpoly.000webhostapp.com/) for my website.
And here is the [source code](https://github.com/North077/Particles.git)

Can anyone help me on how to get the "Install App" option on my website?

I'm fairly new to coding. So excuse my questionable coding skills.

I added a webmanifest.json file in the root directory and linked the icon png. Registered a service worker with a file named sw.js in the root directory. And hosted it via Webhost000 with https.

Comment: Perhaps your manifest does not have the minimum required settings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#manifest

Comment: If you're using chrome for development, you can open Lighthouse in the devtools and analyse the progressive web app category

Comment: My manifest met all the requirements except for the display property, and it passed lighthouse's test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest does not currently have a `display` property. For further edits please open the applications windows inside a chromium browser. It will tell you exactly what you are missing. Also, the chrome lighthouse is a good tab to check for this.

Comment: Yeap, my manifest didn't have the display property, I added it to my manifest and I had the install app option on both firefox and brave but not on chrome. But, it turns out, chrome requires you to cache all your files in order to get the Install App option. I edited my service worker so that it caches all the files and it works now. Thanks!